# Can you redirect just stderr in GDB with tcsh as the shell?

Tags: gdb

I am debugging some code, and when I step through one thread, I get a ton of timeout error messages printed to STDERR from another thread. I'd like to hide everything printed to stderr. I tried using redirection when starting the app:

```
(gdb) run 2> /dev/null
```

but this appears to be redirecting stdout as well, and I need that to call pretty print functions on my objects while stepping through code.

PS I am using GDB 7.2, and no I can't upgrade :(

PPS I wouldn't think this would be shell dependent, but I'm running tcsh 6.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the root cause was using tcsh. It doesn't have any way to redirect just stderr, and gdb is apparently passing these redirection strings to the shell to interpret. There are [hacks to work around this at the command-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134358/38146), but I couldn't get them to work inside GDB. If you use a sane shell then [invalid entry's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25123595/339595) would work. I never got a chance to test [the paul's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30081384/339595) as I was off that project by that time, but it might work with tcsh. I'll change the selected answer if someone does verify it works.

Answer (score 5):

Try the 'set args' command:

```
(gdb) set args 2>/dev/null
(gdb) run
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it redirected both the input and output the same as my original example above did.

Answer (score 1):

[*Edit:* @invalid-entry's answer is correct. At least with a suitably recent gdb, you can do per-fd redirection on the `set args` or `run` command. I'm not sure when exactly gdb learned how to do that. If it's not working for you, the below solution might still be useful.]

<strike>I don't think there's a way to do this with the plain shell redirections recognized by the `run` command.</strike> However, you *could* use gdb to redirect the inferior's stderr stream to a file manually.

Something like

```
# get the program started
break __libc_start_main
run
# open a new filehandle to /dev/null. the 1 is the value of the
# O_WRONLY constant, cause we want to open /dev/null in write mode.
set $nullfd = open("/dev/null", 1)
# make fd 2 (stderr) be a copy of that new handle
call dup2($nullfd, 2)
# we can close the new handle now (optional)
call close($nullfd)
# let the program carry on
cont
```

would do the job, overriding whatever used to be open at fd 2 (the thing that was there before was probably a handle to your terminal.) After this point, any writes to stderr will go to `/dev/null`.

Obviously, this may require tweaks depending on your platform. You might not have a `__libc_start_main` symbol in your executable; `main` might work instead.